# SQL query Optimization help

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, optimization, query-optimization

I have the the following SQL query

```
Declare @tempcalctbl Table
(
    ItemId varchar(50),
    ItemLocation varchar(50),
    ItemNo varchar(50),
    Width real,
    Unit varchar(50),
    date datetime
)

Insert Into @tempcalctbl 
     Select distinct SubId,ItemLocation,ItemNo,
       (ABS((Select width From @temptbl a Where ItemProcess ='P1'and a.ItemId = c.ItemId 
           and a.ItemNo = c.ItemNo and a.ItemLocation = c.ItemLocation)
       -(Select width From @temptbl b Where ItemProcess ='P2' and b.ItemId = c.ItemId 
           and b.ItemNo = c.ItemNo and b.ItemLocation = c.ItemLocation))) * 1000,
       Unit,date
From @temptbl c
Group by ItemId,ItemLocation,ItemNo,Unit,date
```

I was wondering how to optimize this query.
The idea is to find out the different in width (p1's item - p2's item) between ItemProcess 'P1' and 'P2' according to the same ItemID, same ItemNo and same ItemLocation.
I have around 75000 and it took more then 25 minute to get the width differences for all the ItemId.

I tried to use Group by for the width different calculation but it would return multiple row instead of just a value which then would return error. By the way I am use MS SQL server 2008 and @tempcalctbl is a table that I declared in a store procedure.

Comment: Are you just trying to get the difference between the max and min widths for a specific productID?

Comment: You might be able to get this portion of the query quicker by going against @temptbl only once, however I suspect that the overall process of dumping to @temptbl and then cascading to another @table variable should be investigated. Why do you think it's only this portion of the query that takes 25 minutes? Did you time the initial population of @temptbl (and any other work that is done first)?

Comment: @Brian Hoover I am trying to get a width different from all the ItemID.

Comment: @Aaron Ya I did time the initial population of @temptbl. I run the sql code seperately example run initial population of @temptbl and so on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does the following help?

```
INSERT  INTO @tempcalctbl
SELECT  P1.SubId ,
        P1.ItemLocation ,
        P1.ItemNo ,
        ABS(P1.Width - P2.Width) * 1000 AS Width ,
        P1.Unit ,
        P1.date
FROM    @temptbl AS P1
        INNER JOIN @temptbl AS P2 ON P1.ItemId = P2.ItemId
                                     AND P1.ItemNo = P2.ItemNo
                                     AND P1.ItemLocation = P2.ItemLocation
WHERE   P1.ItemProcess = 'P1'
        AND P2.ItemProcess = 'P2'
```

---

### **EDIT**

To make use of indexes, you will need to change your table variable to a temporary table

```
CREATE TABLE #temptbl
(
    ItemId varchar(50),
    ItemLocation varchar(50),
    ItemNo varchar(50),
    Width real,
    Unit varchar(50),
    date DATETIME,
    ItemProcess INT,
    SubId INT
)

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX Index01 ON #temptbl
(
    ItemProcess ASC,
    ItemId ASC,
    ItemLocation ASC,
    ItemNo ASC
)
INCLUDE ( SubId,Width,Unit,date)
GO
```

That should speed you up a little.

Comment: Why did you drop the `GROUP BY`?

Comment: I assumed that he had two rows for every Item,ItemNo,Location combination, His group by to me meant that he wanted to have a single row for both of them by ignoring the ItemProcess column. So that being the case, Just select one of the rows "P1" and join to the other "P2". Should be the same result, but the table is hit twice and not three times. Adding indexes to the temporary table will speed it up and should make it almost instant. But need to make sure my assumption was right first, before I suggest some indexes.

Comment: @John Petrak Tried your query and visually compare the result and it work and shorter time. Let me explain more clearly, I wanted to find out the difference of width for the same Item, same itemNo same Location. All item share the same SubID but with multiple ItemNo and ItemLocation. For example subID abc123 might have ItemLocation(a,b,c) and ItemNo(1,2,3,4,5,6....). Yes I just need to select one of the width with ItemProcess 'P1' and ItemProcess 'P2'Where both of that will give me different width. Mind tell me mroe about the indexes ?

Comment: Updated answer with index info.

Answer (score 0):

John Petrak's answer is the best query for this case.
If the speed is still now acceptable, maybe you can store @temptbl at a temporary real table, and create the related index on those four columns.